# Error tcNull Golang HanadB

Tags: sql, go, hana, go-iris

It happens that I have a database connection called Hana (Hana DB) with the programming language Go (Golang). Using the Iris framework.

What happens is that Go has problems with null data. You have to use special data types in the struct as (using the sql library that comes by default when installing Go) sql.NullString

The question is, I have a GetEmployeeData () function called when connecting to a certain URL and returning a JSON. The problem is that it does not return anything, a CONNECTION error REJECTED appears and in the console it prints an error:
**hdb.protocol 2018/07/13 16:31:06 option.go:120: type code tcNull not implemented exit status 1**
The code was already tested in another SQL call in another function and it works, but this SQL I suppose that when returning 1 only Null or more it gives error.

The code is the following:

```
func GetEmployeeData(ctx iris.Context) {

    const (
        driverName = "hdb"
        hdbDsn     = "hdb://SYSTEM:manager@62.28.253.218:30015"
    )
    //db, err := sql.Open(driverName, hdbDsn)
    //Crea una abstraccion de conexion a base de datos pero no conecta
    //Si no que prepara todo para la conexion
    db, err := sql.Open(driverName, hdbDsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //Declaramos variable de QUERY

    //var peticion = GetCompanyData()
    //fmt.Println(peticion)
    // var companyData = GetCompanyData()
    var request = `Select
                                    "U_idcodigo",
                                    "U_idapenom",
                                    "U_idnumint",
                                    "U_ctestado",
                                    "U_idemail",
                                    "U_cttipfun",
                                    "U_uocodcar",
                                    TO_CHAR("U_uocarasi",'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                    "U_uocodfun",
                                    TO_CHAR("U_uofunasi",'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                    "U_idestciv",
                                    "U_idsexo",
                                    "U_idnacion",
                                    "U_codcat",
                                    "U_codesp",
                                    TO_CHAR("U_idfecnac",'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                    "U_idfotogr",
                                    "U_dodirecc","
                                    U_docodpai",
                                    "U_doregion",
                                    "U_doprovin",
                                    "U_docomuna",
                                    "U_docodpos",
                                    "U_donummov",
                                    "U_cttipcon",
                                    TO_CHAR("U_ctfecing",'dd/mm/yyyy'),

                                    "U_uolugpag",                                      
                                    "U_uolugtra",
                                    "U_uocodger",
                                    "U_uocoddep",
                                    "U_uocodsec",                        
                                    "U_rpforpag",
                                    "U_rpcodban",
                                    "U_rpctacte",
                                    "U_rptipocta",
                                    "U_rpunisal",
                                    "U_rpmoneda",
                                    TO_VARCHAR("U_rpsalar"),
                                    "U_tijor",
                                    TO_VARCHAR("U_hdia"),
                                    TO_VARCHAR("U_cthorcon"),
                                    "U_sindi",
                                    "U_jubil",
                                    "U_turno",
                                    TO_CHAR("U_turnoasi",'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                    "U_comentar"
                                    FROM SBODemoCL."@A1A_MAFU"
                                    Where "U_idcodigo" = '7579684-6'`

    rows, err := db.Query(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("No funciono la peticion")
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println("Funciono la peticion")

    type Employee struct {
        CodigoEmpleado sql.NullString `json:"CodigoEmpleado"` //CODIGO UNICO DE EMPLEADO
        Nombres        sql.NullString `json:"Nombres"`        //APELLIDO Y NOMBRE
        NroInterno     sql.NullString `json:"NroInterno"`     //NUMERO INTERNO EN EMPRESA
        Estado         sql.NullString `json:"Estado"`
        Email          sql.NullString `json:"Email"`        //CORREO ELECTRONICO
        TipoF          sql.NullString `json:"TipoF"`        //TIPO DE FUNCIONARIO
        Cargo          sql.NullString `json:"Cargo"`        //EL CARGO QUE OCUPA EL EMPLEADO
        FechaCargo     sql.NullString `json:"FechaCargo"`   //FECHA DE ASIGNACION DE CARGO
        Funcion        sql.NullString `json:"Funcion"`      //QUE FUNCION CUMPLE
        FechaFuncion   sql.NullString `json:"FechaFuncion"` //CUANDO SE LE ASIGNO SU FUNCION
        Civil          sql.NullString `json:"Civil"`        //ESTADO CIVIL
        Sexo           sql.NullString `json:"Sexo"`         //SI ES MASCULINO O FEMENINO
        Nacionalidad   sql.NullString `json:"Nacionalidad"` //SU NACIONALIDAD
        Categoría      sql.NullString `json:"Categoría"`    //SU CATEGORIA
        Especialidad   sql.NullString `json:"Especialidad"` //SU ESPECIALIDAD
        Nacimiento     sql.NullString `json:"Nacimiento"`   //FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
        Fotografia     sql.NullString `json:"Fotografia"`   //RUTA DE MAPA DE BITS DE IMAGEN SOBRE EL EMPLEADO
        Direccion      sql.NullString `json:"Direccion"`    //DIRECCION DE CASA DEL EMPLEADO
        Pais           sql.NullString `json:"Pais"`         //PAIS EN DONDE SE ENCUENTRA ACTUALMENTE
        Region         sql.NullString `json:"Region"`       //REGION DONDE SE ENCUENTRA ACTUALMENTE
        Provincia      sql.NullString `json:"Provincia"`    //PROVINCIA DONDE SE ENCUENTRA ACTUALMENTE
        Comuna         sql.NullString `json:"Comuna"`       //COMUNA DONDE SE ENCUENTRA ACTUALMENTE
        C_Postal       sql.NullString `json:"C_Postal"`     //SU CODIGO POSTAL
        Celular        sql.NullString `json:"Celular"`      //NUMERO DE CELULAR
        TipoContrato   sql.NullString `json:"TipoContrato"` //TIPO DE CONTRATO
        FechaIngreso   sql.NullString `json:"FechaIngreso"` //FECHA DE INGRESO A LA COMPAÑIA

        LugarPago      sql.NullString `json:"LugarPago"`      //LUGAR DONDE NORMALMENTE COBRA EL EMPLEADO
        LugarTrabajo   sql.NullString `json:"LugarTrabajo"`   //LUGAR DONDE NORMALMENTE TRABAJA EL EMPLEADO
        Gerencia       sql.NullString `json:"Gerencia"`       //¿Quien es su genente? No es claro
        Departamento   sql.NullString `json:"Departamento"`   //¿Si tiene departamento? ¿O la ubicacion de su departamento? ¿O con departamento se refieren a su partido o barrio?
        Seccion        sql.NullString `json:"Seccion"`        //¿? Tampoco me queda claro
        FormaPago      sql.NullString `json:"FormaPago"`      //COMO SE LE PAGA NORMALMENTE AL EMPLEADO
        Banco          sql.NullString `json:"Banco"`          //EL BANCO QUE SE UTILIZA PARA DEPOSITAR EL SALARIO DEL EMPLEADO
        CuentaBanco    sql.NullString `json:"CuentaBanco"`    //CUENTA BANCARIO DONDE SE DEPOSITA EL SALARIO
        UnidadSalarial sql.NullString `json:"UnidadSalarial"` //¿? Su unidad salarial
        Moneda         sql.NullString `json:"Moneda"`         //CON QUE TIPO DE MONEDA SE DEPOSITA SU SUELDO (EUROS, DOLARES, PESOS, ETC...)
        Sueldo         sql.NullString `json:"Sueldo"`         //SUELDO BASICO DEL EMPLEADO
        TipoJornada    sql.NullString `json:"TipoJornada"`    //TIPO DE JORNADA DEL EMPLEADO (CANTIDAD DE HORAS QUE TRABAJA)
        HorasDia       sql.NullString `json:"HorasDia"`       //HORAS DIARIAS QUE ESTIPULA EL CONTRATO
        HorasMes       sql.NullString `json:"HorasMes"`       //HORAS MENSUALES QUE ESTIPULA EL CONTRATO
        Sindicato      sql.NullString `json:"Sindicato"`      //SINDICATO AL QUE PERTENECE EL EMPLEADO
        Jubilido       sql.NullString `json:"Jubilido"`       //¿? Puede ser si es que esta jubilado o no
        Turno          sql.NullString `json:"Turno"`          //¿Turno de que?
        FechaTurno     sql.NullString `json:"FechaTurno"`     //FECHA EN QUE SE LE ASIGNO EL TURNO
        Comentarios    sql.NullString `json:"Comentarios"`    //Comentarios sobre el empleado
    }

    // numero := 0
    //
    // ac := accounting.Accounting{
    //  Symbol:    "",                        //El símbolo
    //  Precision: 2,                         // ¿Cuántos "centavos" queremos? (también llamado precisión)
    //  Thousand:  companyData["ISeparator"], //Separador de miles
    //  Decimal:   companyData["FSeparator"], //Separador de decimales
    // }

    employ := new(Employee)

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(
            &employ.CodigoEmpleado,
            &employ.Nombres,
            &employ.NroInterno,
            &employ.Estado,
            &employ.Email,
            &employ.TipoF,
            &employ.Cargo,
            &employ.FechaCargo,
            &employ.Funcion,
            &employ.FechaFuncion,
            &employ.Civil,
            &employ.Sexo,
            &employ.Nacionalidad,
            &employ.Categoría,
            &employ.Especialidad,
            &employ.Nacimiento,
            &employ.Fotografia,
            &employ.Direccion,
            &employ.Pais,
            &employ.Region,
            &employ.Provincia,
            &employ.Comuna,
            &employ.C_Postal,
            &employ.Celular,
            &employ.TipoContrato,
            &employ.FechaIngreso,

            &employ.LugarPago,
            &employ.LugarTrabajo,
            &employ.Gerencia,
            &employ.Departamento,
            &employ.Seccion,
            &employ.FormaPago,
            &employ.Banco,
            &employ.CuentaBanco,
            &employ.UnidadSalarial,
            &employ.Moneda,
            &employ.Sueldo,
            &employ.TipoJornada,
            &employ.HorasDia,
            &employ.HorasMes,
            &employ.Sindicato,
            &employ.Jubilido,
            &employ.Turno,
            &employ.FechaTurno,
            &employ.Comentarios,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(valor6, 64)
        // salario := ac.FormatMoney(f)

    }

    err = rows.Err()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("Ocurrio un error")
    }
    ctx.JSON(employ)
}
```

The libraries that are imported are the following:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/kataras/iris"
    "github.com/leekchan/accounting"
    // Register hdb driver.
    _ "github.com/SAP/go-hdb/driver"
)
```

The error calls an option.go file. All the code of option go is the following:

```
    /*
Copyright 2014 SAP SE

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

package protocol

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/SAP/go-hdb/internal/bufio"
)

type booleanType bool

func (t booleanType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%t", t)
}

type intType int32

func (t intType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", t)
}

type bigintType int64

func (t bigintType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", t)
}

type doubleType float64

func (t doubleType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%g", t)
}

type stringType []byte

type binaryStringType []byte

func (t binaryStringType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", []byte(t))
}

//multi line options (number of lines in part header argumentCount)
type multiLineOptions []plainOptions

func (o multiLineOptions) size() int {
    size := 0
    for _, m := range o {
        size += m.size()
    }
    return size
}

//pointer: append multiLineOptions itself
func (o *multiLineOptions) read(rd *bufio.Reader, lineCnt int) {
    for i := 0; i < lineCnt; i++ {
        m := plainOptions{}
        cnt := rd.ReadInt16()
        m.read(rd, int(cnt))
        *o = append(*o, m)
    }
}

func (o multiLineOptions) write(wr *bufio.Writer) {
    for _, m := range o {
        wr.WriteInt16(int16(len(m)))
        m.write(wr)
    }
}

    type plainOptions map[int8]interface{}

    func (o plainOptions) size() int {
        size := 2 * len(o) //option + type
        for _, v := range o {
            switch v := v.(type) {
            default:
                outLogger.Fatalf("type %T not implemented", v)
            case booleanType:
                size++
            case intType:
                size += 4
            case bigintType:
                size += 8
            case doubleType:
                size += 8
            case stringType:
                size += (2 + len(v)) //length int16 + string length
            case binaryStringType:
                size += (2 + len(v)) //length int16 + string length
            }
        }
        return size
    }

    func (o plainOptions) read(rd *bufio.Reader, cnt int) {

        for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {

            k := rd.ReadInt8()
            tc := rd.ReadB()

            switch TypeCode(tc) {

            default:
                outLogger.Fatalf("type code %s not implemented", TypeCode(tc))

            case tcBoolean:
                o[k] = booleanType(rd.ReadBool())

            case tcInteger:
                o[k] = intType(rd.ReadInt32())

            case tcBigint:
                o[k] = bigintType(rd.ReadInt64())

            case tcDouble:
                o[k] = doubleType(rd.ReadFloat64())

            case tcString:
                size := rd.ReadInt16()
                v := make([]byte, size)
                rd.ReadFull(v)
                o[k] = stringType(v)

            case tcBstring:
                size := rd.ReadInt16()
                v := make([]byte, size)
                rd.ReadFull(v)
                o[k] = binaryStringType(v)

            }
        }
    }

    func (o plainOptions) write(wr *bufio.Writer) {

        for k, v := range o {

            wr.WriteInt8(k)

            switch v := v.(type) {

            default:
                outLogger.Fatalf("type %T not implemented", v)

            case booleanType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcBoolean))
                wr.WriteBool(bool(v))

            case intType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcInteger))
                wr.WriteInt32(int32(v))

            case bigintType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcBigint))
                wr.WriteInt64(int64(v))

            case doubleType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcDouble))
                wr.WriteFloat64(float64(v))

            case stringType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcString))
                wr.WriteInt16(int16(len(v)))
                wr.Write(v)

            case binaryStringType:
                wr.WriteInt8(int8(tcBstring))
                wr.WriteInt16(int16(len(v)))
                wr.Write(v)
            }
        }
    }
```

If someone wants to download the library in their Go folder this is the command:

go get github.com/SAP/go-hdb/driver

This is your Github link: https://github.com/SAP/go-hdb

Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is complaining "I don't know how to read a null value."

The options.go file's read function has a switch statement at line 117 that implements the ways to read various database types. You will need to update this switch statement to be able to handle a null ("tcNull"?) type value.

Comment: Yes. I know it but i don't know how to do that